# How to keep weblogic running after closing putty window

Tags: weblogic, startup, putty

I’ve started weblogic through putty:

```
./startWebLogic.sh
```

After that server started successfully.

But when I close the putty window, the server stops working

How can I keep weblogic running after I close the putty window?

Thanks!

Comment: Clarified the purpose of the post

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will want to use something like the following:

`nohup ./startWebLogic.sh &`

Nohup is a unix command, used to start another program, in such a way that it does not terminate when the parent process is terminated.

You can also output it to a file if you'd like:

`nohup ./startWebLogic.sh > admin_server.out &`

Comment: Thanks. What will be the location of the output file?

Comment: In the case above, it is the same as your `startWebLogic.sh` file. You can specify where it should go via normal unix commands like `> /path/you.want/admin_server.out`

Answer (score 0):

Simple Steps:
after the login through putty follow the below steps:

1. Go directory of server where "startWebLogic.sh" this command located.
2. typed command "screen" press enter (A new Screen will opened)
3. In the new screen type your run command "./startWebLogic.sh".
4. Press Ctrl+a then press d(without holding Ctrl) you will return back previous screen)
5. if like to go again your server log screen typed command "screen -r"

Akbar